# Javascript: Un-able to create new hidden input element

Tags: javascript, security

I was following the code found in [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) to create a secure login page. The trouble is, it can't create the hidden input element.

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be out hashed password field.
    var p = document.createElement("input");
    // Add the new element to our form.
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden"
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
    password.value = "";
    // Finally submit the form.
    form.submit();
}
```

I have read through saying that it only works for IE and not for gecko. Is this true or I just missing something?

Update:

The formhash function works when I place the javascript into the login page. When it is move to an external file, the problem starts again.

@asprin Noted. The reason I place php is because the code was based on php implementation

@Henrik Will do that. Thanks

@RenePot Yup, it was called on the process_login.php page

@MarkGarcia Thanks for the suggestion. Notice it say's that the function wasn't declare

@WernerVesterås Not sure but I think after.

@Quentin Thanks for the suggestion. Will do that :D

Comment: What happens? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Better remove the 'php' tag from this question as it seems to be purely js related

Comment: Please put your code on something like jsfiddle.net to make it easier for us to help.

Comment: If you are using firebug, then see what happens to your html code when and after the script is executed

Comment: Do you call this function before or after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: I hope that you don't hex_sha512 the password when people log in as well as when they create the password. Otherwise you are still using a plain text password. If you want to protect your passwords then the client should send the password using SSL, and the server should hash the password and store and compare hashed passwords not submitted passwords.

Comment: @Quentin Definitely right. To Iso: hash your passwords at the server.

Comment: @JamesAllardice The errors mention about the function wasn't declare

Answer (score 1):

Likely, `form` is simply not set to what you think it is, a jsfiddle.net would probably help us and you debug. I set a working version up at http://jsfiddle.net/JPTyj/ Comment out hidden to actually see it work. *Note that you will not the the hidden input field in "view source" in the browser as it is dynamically added to the dom! Use firebug or the chrome dev tools to see it.*

Also, most likely you will want to use a library to make it easier for you to develop platform independent code instead of writing bare javascript.

Comment: True, I changed it to be more general.

Comment: Hehehe... You didn't know that I'm wrong. (I've already removed my comment.)

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 (at least), you need to set the `type` attribute before appending it using `setAttribute()`:

```
var p = document.createElement("input");
p.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
form.appendChild(p);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BePGD/ Tested in IE7, IE8, Chrome.